# Avoid downloading the files from the browser

Tags: .net, iis

i have a webapplication/webservice deployed on the server it basically have a folder under which we have some files.
I am using a winforms application with httpresponse to access the files and download that to the user system.
now if i try to access the file directly in the web browser like https://weburl/files/test.xls
i can download the file directly. can i avoid this??

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is YES.

The long answer is complicated since you don't provide any details :-(

There several options (IP filtering, User-agent filtering etc.) BUT the standard and IMO best option is to implement authentication+authorization on the server-side and let your application authenticate itself. I would even recommend using SSL so that anything going over the wire is properly encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to configuration section of your web application web.config file:

```
<location path="files">
    <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
         </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: ok will try this.. however if i do this will it affect my current code coz i am using a .net code to download the file from the same path

Comment: @Sathish if you do this then your application can't download the files anymore.

Comment: OK, I thought you serve the files through that web app/service

Comment: i just did this but still i am able to download the files directly from the IE. Please note that it happens only with valid credentials, however i dont have access to files folder path